# Литература о снифферах, сетевых анализаторах

Tags: безопасность, сниффер, анализатор

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу, статьи о программных сетевых анализаторах (снифферах, анализаторах сетевого трафика). Нужна информация о принципах работы данных программ, особенностях их разработки, вопросах информационной безопасности.

Comment: filetype:pdf wireshark

Comment: принцип работы простой: просим сетевую карту отдавать нам весь трафик. (через соответствующие функции ОС). разбираем. делаем что то исходя из полученных данных. А все остальное надо искать не в специализированной литературе по снифферам , а в литературе и стандартах на сетевые протоколы.